# REGEX: Allow any characters including line break

Tags: regex, odk

I want to limit the number of characters allowed in one of the questions in my ODK Xform. The question is about the user's comment so I need the field to accept any number of characters from 0 to 100 including line breaks. Otherwise it must show the proper alert.

```
<bind nodeset="/widgets/Comment" type="string" constraint="regex(.,'^.{0,100}$')" />
```

I have the above code, but it does not allow me to have line breaks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: `.` matches everything except linebreaks. Instead of `.` use `(.|\n)`

Comment: Thank you @RobinGertenbach! It works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `s` option to make `.` match any character, including newlines:

```
<bind nodeset="/widgets/Comment" type="string" constraint="regex(.,'^(?s).{0,100}$')" />
```